# There is no effect of required=False to Serializer in Serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Serializers:

```
class AvatarBaseSerializer(Serializer):
    uuid = ReadOnlyField()
    user = UserBaseSerializer(read_only=True)
    name = CharField(allow_blank=True)
    GENDER = (("M", "Man"), ("W", "Woman"))
    gender = ChoiceField(choices=GENDER)
    body = BodySerializer(partial=True, required=False)
    head = HeadBaseSerializer(read_only=True)
    head_pk = IntegerField(write_only=True)
    head_adjust = HeadAdjustBaseSerializer(partial=True, required=False)
    hair = HairBaseSerializer(read_only=True)
    hair_pk = UUIDField(write_only=True)
    hair_adjust = HairAdjustBaseSerializer(partial=True, required=False)
    thumbnail = ImageField(required=False, allow_null=True)
```

Viewsets:

```
class AvatarViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Avatar.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AvatarBaseSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.UserIsRequestUserPermission,)

    ...

    def partial_update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.check_thumbnail_file_size(request)
        return super().partial_update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I send below parameters by PATCH method. However Django rest framework returns 400 Bad Request("Invalid Input").

```
{
  "head_pk": 1,
  "hair_pk": "89d4c318-c9bf-42cd-b4c4-b7e70a2c8f40",
  "name": "gewgew",
  "gender": "W"
}
```

I want to send parameters without body, head_adjust, hair_adjust.

Comment: Post the error details. It must have pointed out the fields with errors

Answer (score 0):

When validation is applied to a ModelSerializer, both the serializer fields, and their corresponding model fields must correctly validate. If you have optional fields on your model, make sure to correctly set `blank=True` on the model field, as well as setting `required=False` on the serializer field

[you can see it in Docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer)

Comment: I set blank=True at Avatar.body, Avatar.head_adjust, Avatar.hair_adjust, but it raises same error ;(